# How to hide onScroll header in ionic 4?

Tags: ionic4

I want to hide the header on scroll in Ionic 4 Beta 5.

I tried all the directives solutions, but none of them work for me.
So, are there any methods that work?

Answer (score 0):

Use below directive

```
import { IonContent, DomController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer2, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

    @Directive({
      selector: '[scrollHide]'
      })
export class ScrollHideDirective {

  @Input('scrollHide') config: ScrollHideConfig;
  @Input('scrollContent') scrollContent: IonContent;

  contentHeight: number;
  scrollHeight: number;
  lastScrollPosition: number;
  lastValue: number = 0;

  constructor(private element: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2, private  domCtrl: DomController) {
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if(this.scrollContent && this.config) {
      this.scrollContent.scrollEvents = true;

      let scrollStartFunc = async (ev) => {
        const el = await this.scrollContent.getScrollElement();
        this.contentHeight = el.offsetHeight;
        this.scrollHeight = el.scrollHeight;
        if (this.config.maxValue === undefined) {
          this.config.maxValue = this.element.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
        }
        this.lastScrollPosition = el.scrollTop;
      };

      if(this.scrollContent && this.scrollContent instanceof IonContent) {
        this.scrollContent.ionScrollStart.subscribe(scrollStartFunc);
        this.scrollContent.ionScroll.subscribe(async (ev) => this.adjustElementOnScroll(ev));
        this.scrollContent.ionScrollEnd.subscribe(async (ev) => this.adjustElementOnScroll(ev));

      } else if(this.scrollContent instanceof HTMLElement) {
        (this.scrollContent as HTMLElement).addEventListener('ionScrollStart', scrollStartFunc);
        (this.scrollContent as HTMLElement).addEventListener('ionScroll',async (ev) => this.adjustElementOnScroll(ev));
        (this.scrollContent as HTMLElement).addEventListener('ionScrollEnd',async (ev) => this.adjustElementOnScroll(ev));
      }
    }
  }

  private adjustElementOnScroll(ev) {
    if (ev) {
      this.domCtrl.write(async () => {
        const el = await this.scrollContent.getScrollElement();
        let scrollTop: number = el.scrollTop > 0 ? el.scrollTop : 0;
        let scrolldiff: number = scrollTop - this.lastScrollPosition;
        this.lastScrollPosition = scrollTop;
        let newValue = this.lastValue + scrolldiff;
        newValue = Math.max(0, Math.min(newValue, this.config.maxValue));
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.element.nativeElement, this.config.cssProperty, `-${newValue}px`);
        this.lastValue = newValue;
      });
    }
  }
}

export interface ScrollHideConfig {
  cssProperty: string;
  maxValue: number;
}
```

**Steps to use**:
In your HTML

```
<ion-header [scrollHide]="headerScrollConfig" [scrollContent]="pageContent">
.
.
.
<ion-content #pageContent>
```

In your controller: Add config variables

```
footerScrollConfig: ScrollHideConfig = { cssProperty: 'margin-bottom', maxValue: undefined };
headerScrollConfig: ScrollHideConfig = { cssProperty: 'margin-top', maxValue: 54 };
```

Comment: could you please explain a little more? config variables are giving error. 

Thank you in advance.